# Laravel 5.2 & Stripe Source parameter

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I was wondering, in the Laravel documentation when you want to create a charge, it wants the parameter source that equals a token

```
$user->charge(100, [
    'source' => $token,
    'receipt_email' => $user->email,
]);
```

But in stripes official documentation it does not require a token again just a customer stripe id.

```
\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
  "currency" => "dkk",
  "customer" => $customer->id)
);
```

Which token is it exactly Laravel wants? As it works fine without the source parameter i found out, but I'm just curious.

Comment: you'd use customer if you want to save a customer's card and charge it in the future without asking them for card details. The source token is the token generated by Stripe.js or Stripe Checkout which is a PCI compliant representation of a card

Comment: Yeah i do have `$customer = $user->createAsStripeCustomer(Input::get('stripeToken'));` which saves their card details too stripe, how do i retrive this token, if i wanna charge them then like 3 weeks from now?, or add them to a subscription? @MatthewArkin

Comment: you don't retrieve the token, you retrieve the customer and you charge a customer not the token

Comment: Thats what i thought, i just don't understand looking at the Laravel doc it want a $creditcardtoken then.... https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing#creating-subscriptions Bu thanks for the clarification @MatthewArkin

Comment: If the customer already has a credit card saved then $creditcardtoken should be optional

Comment: Hmm ok, it does works with an empty token, but it still require's it to have a variable. Thanks for the help though!